# How do I search for and extract information from MANIFEST.MF in my Classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, manifest

I search through all manifests in all jars in my application, locating just the ones I am interested in (those from my org, not those from libraries) and pull the version information and a few other custom attributes.

So let's break this down...

1. Search the classpath... what about jars that I have not yet loaded any classes from?
2. Open the manifests, iterate through the entries and filter the ones I need...

Comment: Are you using OSGi?

Comment: Not yet. Soon, and not on this project...